# Application Lifecycle for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xna, monogame

I'm porting a XNA game to iOS using MonoGame and VisualStudio for Mac. In the original source code I used `PhoneApplicationService` to manage the application lifecycle:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Launching += OnGameLaunching;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Closing += OnGameClosing;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated += OnGameDeactivated;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += OnGameActivated;
```

I used `PhoneApplicationService` in a class derived from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` so that I could manage the lifecycle with events inside the game loop.

To port the game to iOS, I know I need to use `UIKit` and provide an `AppDelegate` like this (the code below comes from a Xamarin example):

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
class Program : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    private static Game1 game;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }

    public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app)
    {
        game = new Game1();
        game.Run(); // does not return until the game doesn't end
    }

    public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
    { 
        // pause the stopwatch
        ...
    }

    public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
    { 
        // resume the stopwatch
        ...
    }
}
```

In the code above, `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()` is invoked in `FinishedLaunching()` and it returns only when the game actually ends. That being said, I'm wondering whether `OnResignActivation()` and `OnActivated()` get still invoked when the application goes into a background state or when is moved back to an active state, respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run() in FinishedLaunching() only returns when the game ends`? `FinishedLaunching`  invoked after the application has launched to configure the main window and view controller. It's the start of the application instead of ending.

Comment: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run() executes the game loop and does not return... so I’m wondering how I could handle other events like OnActivated or DidEnterBackground. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small test app and I confirm that `OnResignActivation()` and `OnActivated()` get invoked even though `game.Run()` doesn't return until the game doesn't end.